# Fatal errors trying to install gtk on Mac (Mavericks)

Tags: haskell, gtk, installation

I guess I'm a glutton for punishment. I'm trying (again) to install gk on my Mac so I can experiment with it from Haskell. I'm following the instructions at http://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php and was in the middle of the **jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-bootstrap** phase

The build failed with Python errors (see log below) and a popup dialog (Python quit unexpectedly while using the libpython2.7.dylib plug-in)

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
--------------
Making all in doc
Making all in gnome-doc-make
  XML2PO de/gnome-doc-make.xml
  XML2PO de/legal.xml
  XML2PO de/make-ref.xml
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
/bin/sh: line 1: 85775 Abort trap: 6           PYTHONPATH="/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po:/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7/site-packages" "/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po/xml2po/xml2po" -m docbook -e -t "${mo}" "${d}C/make-ref.xml" > make-ref.xml.tmp
make[2]: *** [de/make-ref.xml] Error 134
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh: line 1: 85767 Abort trap: 6           PYTHONPATH="/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po:/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7/site-packages" "/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po/xml2po/xml2po" -m docbook -e -t "${mo}" "${d}C/gnome-doc-make.xml" > gnome-doc-make.xml.tmp
make[2]: *** [de/gnome-doc-make.xml] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 85773 Abort trap: 6           PYTHONPATH="/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po:/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0:/Users/dhj/gtk/inst/lib/python2.7/site-packages" "/Users/dhj/gtk/source/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10/doc/gnome-doc-make/../../xml2po/xml2po/xml2po" -m docbook -e -t "${mo}" "${d}C/legal.xml" > legal.xml.tmp
make[2]: *** [de/legal.xml] Error 134
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had this issue it was because of an odd mix of Python versions on my machine. The simple fix is to run **jhbuild build python** before you run **jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-bootstrap** so that the environment has the version it is expecting where it expects it to be.